# How to display the encrypted connection String of the web.config file in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encryption

In my .net web application I encrypted the  of the web.config file.

But now I need to read this encrypted connection String from an external winforms application and display the result in a text box . The text box text would look something like this :

```
 <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="CustomEncryptProvider">
        <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <CipherData>
                        <CipherValue>Smbfcf3dHbuYZ34hLWtATU8fBqNL/CvPk24tLj9gLOizLzV88den52yhtYQ5AwXe2vVZP/GKRsWB+rcX/6ufBkz75HyVOnJHTCgLQ+JcsRX/9Td5ZzWJrEq1JBdpFzBsS9aLGLMREIILPedmFxO5+0GLIaBPzZ9/BhNcN8GXa+k=</CipherValue>
                    </CipherData>
                </EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>raoQqDzlXmMCy+3VliV6oyMoQzgIapSmBKw666WbUjLgurCh4aS+pwSMW3wULOpi+jh8BdDE/aPwvhDw9kTuComyHBsEB4xMtRFaBY1NSyrwx7dnP44x4NS+LowJ1EQiN2fAZqWDDVAljRIlq3DtZhC9YkYl4H1rEjQVvljD0pus1O8ftiqKy/yma1/rqzI+F/87GrFR1ZM8cS/ujXagtfzqME4iVdTgl/eyEPkrd5f6SGwlieeC0zJ2ErV9zIr+Af2Sc6mk2hz7/+t2x3kAzDzHU2PFfBqiLSP6o/0XAdRl43Q/Jwr72552mus7n5urlzvyND0KXKzk4Gg4bVYuo8sSQvphbFuLgHIxq+6ShDdCc9wfMzsBmGU4ayYbn/a4rI8lB5y6GzK0kQvnH0qtWQ==</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
    </connectionStrings>
```

How to achieve the same ? Please note I only have the physical path to the web.config file .

Comment: Why are you encrypting the whole web.config?

Comment: No I am not. I am only encrypting connectionStrings . And I want to display  the same .

Comment: Is your question about how to encrypt/decrypt or is it about how to locate a substring within a larger string?

Comment: I have encrypted the connectionString section already and saved the encrypted config . I want to display the encrypted connectionString back from an external winforms apllication.

Comment: OK, so then are you asking how to decrypt the string that you've already encrypted or are you asking how to find it within the web.config file from the external winforms application?  Or both?

Comment: @greyseal96  "you asking how to find it within the web.config file from the external winforms application? "
Yes the same. I want to find and print the encrypted connection String.

Comment: OK, we're getting there.  How have you encrypted the connection string?  Can you update your question with an example of what you're doing and what the end result looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a config file using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` like this:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(/* path to config file */);
```

The connection strings will automatically be decrypted, and will be available in the `ConnectionStrings` property of the `Configuration` object. In your case, the connection string is called "LocalSqlServer":

```
Console.WriteLine(config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"]);
```

```
> data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

**EDIT**

If, as you've indicated, you actually want the whole content of the `connectionStrings` xml element, you can do this with an `XmlReader`:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(/* path to config file */))
{
    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("connectionStrings"))
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadOuterXml());
}
```

```
 > <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="CustomEncryptProvider">
        <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" etc...
```

Comment: but I want to show the encrypted connection string not the auto - decrypted one.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show "raoQqDzlXmMCy+3VliV6o..."?

Comment: The whole content of the encrypted connection String section

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot . But would it be possible to update connection String using xmlWriter also ? Just a wild guess though :)

Comment: You'd be best off using an `XmlDocument` if you want to change the content, but yes, it can be done.

Comment: It will be much easier to to use your own encrptionon algo (aes for example) to crypt and decrypt data the way you need